# How to Discover Facebook Fake Account Info?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

Someone created a fake Facebook account using my name and my picture; is there a way to discover the phone number or email that was used to create the fake account? How I can discover who did that, and what is the best way to stop it?

Comment: Facebook's not going to give you that information. You should just report it to Facebook and leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

To report someone impersonating you, follow the directions from Facebook:

[How do I report an account for impersonation?](https://www.facebook.com/help/174210519303259)

It is extremely unlikely that they will offer up this information to you, however.